# Retrieving changed rows only from a table with 10^7 rows

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgresql-9.3, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a table with about 300 columns and about 10<sup>7</sup> rows and I have to retrieve changed rows only, ordered by time (not distinct, but changed). The result set may be limited to 100 rows as well.

I've tried the following query with `lag` window function:

```
-- Suppose, we want to retrieve data from column1, column2 and column3 fields
-- There may be other fields, though
SELECT
  w."stamp",
  w."column1",
  w."column2",
  w."column3"
FROM (
       SELECT
         o.stamp,
         o.obj_id,
         "o"."column1",
         "o"."column2",
         "o"."column3",
         lag(o."column1") OVER (ORDER BY stamp) AS "_prev_column1",
         lag(o."column2") OVER (ORDER BY stamp) AS "_prev_column2",
         lag(o."column3") OVER (ORDER BY stamp) AS "_prev_column3" 
       FROM "table_name" o
       WHERE o.stamp BETWEEN '01.12.2015 00:00' AND '23.01.2016 00:00'
       ORDER BY o.stamp DESC
     ) AS w
WHERE 
  w.obj_id = 42 AND w.stamp BETWEEN '01.12.2015 00:00' AND '23.01.2016 00:00' AND 
  ("w"."_prev_column_1", "w"."_prev_column_2", "w"."_prev_column_3") IS DISTINCT FROM
  ("w"."column_1", "w"."column_2", "w"."column_3")
ORDER BY w.stamp DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

However, it takes too much time to complete. Is it possible to optimize this query, or the problem should be solved in another way (e.g., custom function)?

---

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ds_dyn_sequence'::regclass),
  obj_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  stamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  column1 BIGINT,
  column2 BIGINT,
  column3 BIGINT
  -- Other fields, all BIGINT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX obj_id_stamp_key ON table_name USING BTREE (obj_id, stamp);
```

---

The table contains about 10<sup>4</sup> rows per a hour. The table will be limited to three months, so, the total number of rows will approximately be 2*10<sup>7</sup>.

PostgreSQL version: 9.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the version was 9.3 or newer, I would try this rewrite of the query:

```
SELECT
    w.stamp,
    w.column1,
    w.column2,
    w.column3
FROM 
    "table_name" AS w
  JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT p.column1, p.column2, p.column3
      FROM "table_name" AS p
      WHERE p.stamp < w.stamp
        AND p.stamp >= '2015-12-01'::timestamp
      ORDER BY p.stamp DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS p
    ON (w.column1, w.column2, w.column3)
       IS DISTINCT FROM
       (p.column1, p.column2, p.column3)
WHERE w.obj_id = 42 
  AND w.stamp >= '2015-12-01'::timestamp
  AND w.stamp <= '2016-01-23'::timestamp 
ORDER BY w.stamp DESC 
LIMIT 100 ;
```

with the index you have and with an index on `(obj_id, stamp DESC)`

---

Unrelated to efficiency: are you sure that you want to use `BETWEEN` with timestamps? It's more common to work with inclusive-exclusive ranges. In other words, shouldn't this condition:

```
  AND w.stamp <= '2016-01-23'::timestamp
```

be?:

```
  AND w.stamp  < '2016-01-23'::timestamp
```

With `BETWEEN` (and `<=`), you are searching though a range that is 53 whole days long + 1 microsecond (or whatever the accuracy of `timestamp` is).

Comment: I suppose, sub query should also contain `p.obj_id = 42` condition. Works like a charm, thank you! One more question: is there any neat way to select one row, when all the rows contains the same data? Your query returns zero rows in this case: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/23d21/1/0)

Comment: Some notes about `BETWEEN` - this does not matter in my case. Selecting +-1 row at the beginning or the end of a range will not break the algorithm. Thank you for pointing it out, though :)

Comment: @soon:  Use your original query with `LAG` to get a row when all rows contain the same data :)

Answer (score 1):

There's probably no better way to get the expected result.

Some remarks:

You don't have to repeat the `w.stamp BETWEEN '01.12.2015 00:00' AND '23.01.2016 00:00'` in the outer query.

Are you sure that a missing `w.obj_id = 42` is correct? If this was part of the Derived Table the existing index would be useful, otherwise you need one on `stamp`.

For this query the index should include the three columns used in `LAG` to get best performance, but [if you need additional columns] this might be too costly.

Is there no `PARTITION BY` for `LAG`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I definitely missed the `obj_id = 42` part in the sub query

Comment: I would be interested in performance difference between `LAG` and `LATERAL JOIN`, could you add some numbers? Btw, the `ORDER BY` in the Derived Table can be removed, too.

Comment: I've compared two queries, results: [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/soon/29c1ed6c4a969198b3ed)